# Creating User class with Flask-login and PyMongo and retrieving data from MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

**Hi guys,**

I'm a total noob regarding Python and Flaks. As part of my school project, I need to create user registration/login functionality with **Flask** and **PyMongo.**

So basically register a user with the username, email, and user password.
Login user with email and password.
Retrieve from MongoDb user default `profile image` following with profile `date created`, user `username`, and user `email`.

The way we need to do this is to create a User class.
When a user is successfully login they should see displayed on the front-end their `username`, `email`, `default profile image`, and `date` when the user profile was created.
Then the user needs to have an option to upload their **profile image**, **username,** and **email**.

Unfortunately, it has to be **MongoDB** for the database.

My current code is not uploading the User class blueprint to **MongoDB** and I don't know how to upload the **default image** and retrieve user info in the `profile.html`

**Can you help me with this, please?**

Any useful advice is welcome and if you can fix my code that would be great.
If you need more info let me know.

**MY CODE SO FAR:**

**routes.py**

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, redirect, request, session, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from mongoengine import *
from datetime import datetime
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, AddTip, UpdateProfile
if os.path.exists("env.py"):
    import env


app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = os.environ.get("MONGO_DBNAME")
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = os.environ.get("MONGO_URI")
connect("MONGO_DBNAME", host=app.config["MONGO_URI"])
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")


mongo = PyMongo(app)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
login.login_message = "To access your profile, pleas log in!"
login.login_message_category = "log-info"

class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    email = EmailField(unique=True)
    password = BinaryField(required=True)
    age = IntField()
    profile_image = ImageField()
    registered = BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    
    def __init__(self, username, email, date_created):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.date_created = date_created

    @staticmethod
    def is_authenticated():
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def is_active():
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def is_anonymous():
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

    @staticmethod
    def check_password(password_hash, password):
        return check_password_hash(password_hash, password)


@login.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": username})
    if not user:
        return None
    return User(user["username"], user["email"], user["date_created"])
```

****THEN MY REGISTER ROUTE:****

```
@app.route("/registration", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def registration():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = {
            "username" : request.form.get("username").lower(),
            "email" : request.form.get("email"),
            "password" : generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
        }
        mongo.db.users.insert_one(user)
        session["user"] = request.form.get("username").lower()
        flash("Welcome to your new profile", "reg-success")
        return redirect(url_for("profile", username=session["user"]))

    return render_template("registration.html", title="| Register", form=form)
```

****LOG IN ROUTE:****

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"email": form.email.data})
        if user and User.check_password(user["password"], form.password.data):
            user_obj = User(username=user["username"])
            login_user(user_obj)
            next_page = request.args.get("next")
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for("profile"))
        else:
            flash("Invalid username or password", "reg-danger")

    return render_template("login.html", title="| Login", form=form)
```

****PROFILE ROUTE:****

```
@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def profile():
    form = UpdateProfile()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Your details are updated", "reg-success")
    else:
        flash("Pleas check your details", "reg-danger")

    return render_template('profile.html', title='| Profile', form=form)
```